# Controlling RGB LED Light with Raspberry Pi and Python

Tags: python, raspberry-pi3, gpio, led

[I bought this LED light on ebay](https://www.ebay.com/itm/5Pcs-CJMCU-KZQ-WS2812-5050-RGB-LED-Full-Color-Drive-Light-Adjustable-USA/173036454210?ssPageName=STRK%3AMEBIDX%3AIT&_trksid=p2060353.m2749.l2649). The model is CJMCU-KZQ.

My question is, how can I get it to work on a raspberry pi and python? I have looked everywhere but cannot find any documentation for it. Also, keep in mind that this light uses SDA/SCL I2C bus.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the ebay page, it suggests that it uses  WS2812 driver to control the LED. Thankfully, that LED driver is pretty common, which means there is plenty of available (and open-soure) code for it.

Documentation for WS2812 driver: https://cdn-shop.adafruit.com/datasheets/WS2812.pdf

Tutorial on how to use LED strip with WS2812 driver: https://tutorials-raspberrypi.com/connect-control-raspberry-pi-ws2812-rgb-led-strips/

The tutorial is great as covers every step of the process. They end up using the rpi_ws281x python wrapper which has been compiled from c.

Comment: For advanced users who don't need the tutorial - rpi_ws281x can be found here with documentation: https://github.com/jgarff/rpi_ws281x

Comment: if you look at the back of the LED, it has several different inputs, while the LED in the tutorials has only 3 inputs. Do you know which inputs I need to use? There is no mention of SDA/SCL i2c bus in the tutorials.

Comment: It appears that this is a driver to run LED's but not an LED itself. Are you aware of this?